# Build Xamarin.Android azure pipeline getting error XA0000: Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v13.0'

Tags: android, azure, msbuild

Getting error while build azure pipeline. It was working fine till compile target api level v12.0.  Now I updated compile target to v13.0 and it stop building Xamarin.Android azure pipeline and gives error XA0000: Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v13.0'

Solution I tryed:

1. Updated MSBuild version from MSBuild 15.0 to MSBuild 17.0  -Didn't work.
2. Update MSBuild architecture from MSBuild x64 to MSBuild x86 -Didn't work.

Anyone knows how to resolve this error? what should be right configuration? Where can I find proper doc on which configuration required with which android version?

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same issue, the solution for me was changing the agent specification to the latest windows. I've changed from 2019 to 2022 and the build worked.

[image]